# Разархивирование архива RAR программно

Tags: c++, архивация

Цель - программно разархивировать архив в определённую папку.
Язык, как вы наверное поняли из тэгов - C++ .
Писать взаимодействующие с архивами программы ранее не приходилось.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Добрый день!

Вариантов несколько.

1. Написать модуль архивации "с нуля". Очень трудоемко, поэтому не обсуждаем.
2. Взять готовый программный модуль, интегрировать к себе. Вариантов много, [например](https://github.com/vilkov/libunrar).
3. Можно найти исходники unrar и втянуть их к себе в код. Что-нибудь такого [типа](http://www.unrarlib.org/download.html)
4. Еще вариант. При установленном WinRAR (или аналогичном архиваторе) в системе можно его запускать через функцию вызова внешней программы с нужными ключами. Что-то вроде [такого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144879/calling-unrar-exe-using-system-in-c) или [такого](http://programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=191735)